# Get-process computername difference between using . or localhost

Tags: powershell

When I run the following, using the `.` I get a list of processes:

```
get-process -ComputerName .
```

When I use `localhost` I get the following error:

```
get-process -ComputerName localhost

get-process : Couldn't connect to remote machine.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-process -ComputerName localhost
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessComm  
   and
```

I'm using VS Code and running the following version of PS:

[image]

What are the possible reasons for this?

---

If I run the following it comes back with `LAPTOP-E#######` which is obviously not `localhost` - would `csName` usually be set as `localhost` or am I looking in the wrong part of ComputerInfo ?

```
Get-ComputerInfo | Select-Object csName
```

Comment: Check if your `Remote Registry` service is enabled. I think when you use localhost, it tries to connect via that service.

Comment: As @Ash suggested, enabling Remote Registry service should solve your issue. Also, please make sure to consider the security implications of enabling Remote Registry service in your organization before you enable it.

Comment: yes indeed - this confirms it is stopped `get-service | where-object -Property name -like remote*` ... and as @YashGupta mentions and via a quick Google confirm, it seems I'm better leaving it off unless needed

Comment: I think it's generally best to use `$env:COMPUTERNAME` if you want to use this in a script.

Comment: @ash thanks. if you move your comment about remote registry to an answer I'll mark as the answer, as that was the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments you have to enable the `Remote Registry` Windows service for `localhost` to work, because it is treated as a remote machine and the underlying .NET method used in the original cmdlet reads the performance counters from the registry. This is not an issue in newer versions of PowerShell because the `-ComputerName` parameter doesn't exist in the [PowerShell Core version of the cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-7.1).

For anyone considering enabling the `Remote Registry` service, please be warned there are a number of security implications to consider when allowing remote access to a computer's registry. A lot of corporate users may find that this service is disabled via GPO. If you need process information from remote machines, it is better to use WinRM via [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.1).

Generally if you want to refer to the local machine in a script it is best to use the PowerShell environment variable `$env:COMPUTERNAME`.

Comment: Thanks for full explanation Ash